# Swing drag node (file) from JTree to operating system desktop

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtree

In Java Swing how can I drag (DnD) a node from a JTree in my Windows desktop in Swing.  The node is an abstraction of a file.

Currently I can get the node to move a file to my Windows temp directory with a random file name using this command:

```
dge.startDrag(DragSource.DefaultCopyDrop, bufferedImage, new Point(0, 0), node,  this);
```

But I want the node on the desktop with a name I choose.

Comment: *"a node from a JTree in my Windows desktop "* Is this app. only for you? What about users of OS X (I don't think it supports dragging things to the main screen) or *nix (unsure of status of 'desktop' there).

Comment: You need to start by having a look at [Drag and Drop and Data Transfer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html). The complex issue is figuring out what `DataFlavour` the OS will accept as an export. It's likely the at the very least, it will accept a `InputStream` from a file based mime type, maybe `application/octet-stream`, you could also try `text/plain` depending on the type of file it is

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer -- the problem I have is twofold: 1) the files are actually stored in the cloud so the idea is that the DnD first has to asynchronously trigger a download, with a progress bar hooked up in the app.  I can get all of this to work...  but I cannot figure out how to identify the path to the target drop site in order to properly move the file to the drop site location when the download completes?

Comment: *"but I cannot figure out how to identify the path to the target drop site in order to properly move the file to the drop site location when the download completes?"* You don't, the target will request the means by which it wants to obtain information about what you are exporting